# heap exception in another thread cannot generate dump file C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, exception, dump

Currently, I have a problem with dump file. In general, I use the win32 api ***MiniDumpWriteDump*** to generate dump file when my App end with the crash. In most case, it's very useful. However, I found that the dump file cannot be generated when Heap Exception happened in another thread. the mini reproduce in follow section:
main.cpp
//main.cpp file

```
LONG WINAPI createMinidump(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS *apExceptionInfo)
{
    HMODULE mhLib = ::LoadLibraryA("dbghelp.dll");
    MINIDUMPWRITEDUMP pDump = (MINIDUMPWRITEDUMP)::GetProcAddress(mhLib, "MiniDumpWriteDump");

    HANDLE  hFile = ::CreateFileA("core.dmp", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    _MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION ExInfo;
    ExInfo.ThreadId = ::GetCurrentThreadId();
    ExInfo.ExceptionPointers = apExceptionInfo;
    ExInfo.ClientPointers = FALSE;

    pDump(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentProcessId(), hFile, MiniDumpWithFullMemory , &ExInfo, NULL, NULL);
    ::CloseHandle(hFile);
    
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(ExceptionHandler);
    
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLoggingCategory>
#include "testth.h"
#include <QThread>

Q_DECLARE_LOGGING_CATEGORY(MainWindowModule)

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
signals:
    void testsignal();

private slots:

    void on_pushButton_clicked(bool checked);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    TestTh* m_t{Q_NULLPTR};
    QObject* m_To{Q_NULLPTR};

    QThread m_TestTH{};
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

//mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <qnetworkconfigmanager.h>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <qevent.h>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileInfo>

Q_LOGGING_CATEGORY(MainWindowModule,"Main.Window.Module",QtMsgType::QtWarningMsg)

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow),m_t{new TestTh()}
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->m_t->moveToThread(&m_TestTH);

    this->m_TestTH.start();

    connect(this,&MainWindow::testsignal,this->m_t,&TestTh::testSlot);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    this->m_TestTH.quit();

    this->m_TestTH.wait();

    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(bool checked)
{
//    this->m_To->thread();

    emit this->testsignal();
}
```

testth.cpp

```
#ifndef TESTTH_H
#define TESTTH_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class TestTh : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TestTh();
    virtual ~TestTh()=default;
public slots:
    void testSlot();
private:

    QObject* m_A{};
    QObject* m_B{};

};

#endif // TESTTH_H
```

test.cpp

```
#include "testth.h"
#include <QDebug>

TestTh::TestTh()
{

}

void TestTh::testSlot()
{
    auto d=new int[1000];
    delete []d;
    delete []d;
    qDebug()<<"test slot func";
}
```

In above code, the app will be crashed when I push the button. Beacuse, I double delete the array in the member testSlot. However, there is no any dump file generated. after some probe, I have been told that api ***MiniDumpWriteDump*** should be called in target process.Hence, I have some midification to my project, As showing in following section:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

//#include <Windows.h>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDeadlineTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSaveFile>
#include <QStringBuilder>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <mutex>
#include <QDateTime>

#include <QFileInfo>
//#include <minidumpapiset.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <QScopedPointer>
#include <QProcess>

auto WINAPI ExceptionHandler(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS pException)->long
{
    QScopedPointer<QProcess> anotherExe{new QProcess()};
    anotherExe->setWorkingDirectory(qApp->applicationDirPath());
    anotherExe->setProgram(qApp->applicationDirPath() % QStringLiteral("/CrashDumpGuardor.exe"));

    auto pidPro=QString::number(GetCurrentProcessId());

    auto threadId=GetCurrentThreadId();

    char exceptionContent[32768];

    sprintf_s(exceptionContent,sizeof(exceptionContent)/sizeof (exceptionContent[0]),"%p",pException);

    anotherExe->setArguments(QStringList{pidPro,QString::number(threadId),QString::fromLatin1(exceptionContent),qApp->applicationDirPath()});
    anotherExe->start();
    anotherExe->waitForFinished();

    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(ExceptionHandler);
    
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

for more details, I move the ***minidumpwritedump*** to another project named ***CrashDumpGuardor*** an that generate an exe named ***CrashDumpGuardor.exe*** that was placed on my crash app dir.I will create the sub process to call ***CrashDumpGuardor.exe*** with some argument. unfortunately, this method have any affect. there is no dump file generation.

after these attempations, I have tried with google breakpad in the

```
following section:
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <io.h>
#include <QScopedPointer>
#include <QProcess>
#include "breakpad/client/windows/handler/exception_handler.h"
using namespace google_breakpad;

static bool callback(const wchar_t *dump_path, const wchar_t *id,
    void *, EXCEPTION_POINTERS *,
    MDRawAssertionInfo *,
    bool succeeded) {
    if (succeeded)
        qWarning("Dump file created in %s, dump guid is %ws\n", dump_path, id);
    else
        qWarning("Dump failed\n");
    return succeeded;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    ExceptionHandler eh(qApp->applicationDirPath().toStdWString().c_str(), NULL, callback, NULL,
                        ExceptionHandler::HANDLER_ALL);


    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

However, there is also no dump file generation, I'm really have no ideal to handle this problem, can someone give an assistance to me, Thanks!!!!

Comment: Let the system create the dump for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps. This is the only safe way. If you are creating a dump due to your app crashing, you have no idea of the state of your app and whether a dump can be created safely. Using the system to create the dump for you is the only safe way.

Comment: @Mike It's successful to me! No amount of words can express my gratitude to you! thank you, brother!